# How to prove that $ - \frac{\pi i}{2n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{ \frac{\pi i}{2n} + \frac{k \pi i}{n}} = \frac{\pi}{2n \sin(\pi/2n)} $?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'd like to prove that $$  - \frac{\pi  i}{2n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{ \frac{\pi \cdot i}{2n} + \frac{k \cdot \pi \cdot i}{n}} = \frac{\pi}{2n \sin(\pi/2n)} .$$

Up until now, I've tried to do this by noting that this is equal to

$$ - \frac{\pi  i}{2n} e^{\frac{\pi i}{2n}} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{ \Big{(}  \frac{  \pi  i}{n} \Big{)}^{k}} = - \frac{\pi  i}{2n} e^{\frac{\pi i}{2n}} \frac{1-e^{\pi i}}{1-e^{\frac{\pi i}{n}}} = - \frac{\pi i}{2n} \frac{e^{ \frac{\pi i}{2n}}-e^{\pi i (1 + \frac{1}{2n})}}{1-e^{\frac{\pi i}{n}}} \quad (*) $$ After that, I am not entirely sure what to do. I tried using Euler's formula $$ e^{i x} = \cos(x) + i \sin (x)  $$ and using the fact that $$ \sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i} . $$ Using these two facts, I'm able to show that $(*)$ is equal to $$ \frac{2 (\sin(\frac{\pi}{2n}-i \cos(\frac{\pi}{2n})}{1-\cos(\frac{\pi}{n})-i \sin(\frac{\pi}{n})} .$$ I am not sure whether this is the right way to go though.

Do you have any hints/solutions for me to proceed from here? Or should I not have done the last step and go along another path?

Comment: Don't multiply the numerator with $\exp \left(\frac{\pi i}{2n}\right)$, throw that at the denominator.

Comment: $\;e^{\pi i}=-1\;$

Comment: That last expression isn't equal to the one we're seeking according to W|A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ - \frac{\pi  i}{2n} e^{\frac{\pi i}{2n}} \frac{1-e^{\pi i}}{1-e^{\frac{\pi i}{n}}}=-\frac{\pi i}{2n}e^{\frac{\pi i}{2n}}\frac2{1-e^{\frac{\pi i}n}}=-\frac{\pi i}n\frac1{e^{-\frac{\pi i}{2n}}-e^{\frac{\pi i}{2n}}}=-\frac{\pi}{2n}\frac{2i}{e^{-\frac{\pi i}{2n}}-e^{\frac{\pi}{2n}}}=$$

$$=\frac\pi{2n}\frac1{\sin\frac\pi{2n}}$$

Using the definition

$$\sin r=\frac{e^{ir}-e^{-ir}}{2i}\;,\;\;r\in\Bbb R$$